# Predicted values and estimated marginal means

Tags: mixed-model, data-visualization, lsmeans

I am currently working on a statistical analysis project where I implemented a linear mixed model with only a random intercept and several fixed effects. I am considering visualizing the results by plotting both predicted values and estimated marginal means (along with their confidence intervals ) on the same graph. However, I am not sure if this is a valid and acceptable approach.

Therefore, I wanted to ask for some insights and opinions on this matter. Would it make sense to display both predicted values and estimated marginal means on the same graph? Are there any issues or limitations that I should be aware of?

Any advice or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: An estimated marginal mean is one type of prediction from a model. Please edit the question to explain in more detail the nature of the "predicted values" that you are distinguishing from the estimated marginal means. Showing the model summary and what you want to display based on it would help.

Comment: I'm not sure if "valid" quite applies here.  It might be *confusing* to readers, or *unconventional* given the culture of your field, but I can't see how plotting the EMMs is invalid.